# Why concurrent loop is slower than normal loop in this scenario?

Tags: ruby

I am learning Threads in Ruby, from **The Ruby Programming Language** book & found this method which is described as concurrent version of each iterator,

```
module Enumerable
  def concurrently
    map {|item| Thread.new { yield item }}.each {|t| t.join }
  end
end
```

The following code

```
 start=Time.now
 arr.concurrently{ |n| puts n} # Ran using threads
 puts "Time Taken #{Time.now-start}"
```

outputs: `Time Taken 6.6278332`

While

```
start=Time.now
arr.each{ |n| puts n} # Normal each loop
puts "Time Taken #{Time.now-start}"
```

outputs: `Time Taken 0.132975928`

Why is it faster without threads ? Is the implementation wrong or the second one has only `puts` statement while the initial one took time for resource allocation/initialization/terminating the Threads ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Threads in MRI (the "gold standard" ruby) are not really concurrent. There's a Global VM Lock (GVL) which prevents threads from running concurrently. It allows, however, other threads to run when the current thread is blocked on I/O, but that's not your case.

So, your code runs serially, and you have threading overhead (creating/destroying threads, etc). That's why it's slower.